# Rails app - pass value to record via ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm struggling with the URL parameter when it comes to AJAX request. What I basically want to do is following - there is a little calculator on my page (it's a shop), the result is displayed in the div #priceValue. I want to pass that value via Ajax to my record.

So here is my view:

```
=form_for :line_item, url: line_items_path(product_id: @product.id), remote: true do |f|
...some fields and calculator goes in there...
=button_tag(type: 'submit', id: 'add_item_to_cart', class: 'btn btn-primary shopping-cart-btn') do
                      %i.fa.fa-shopping-cart
                      Buy
```

Lineitems are sort of join model, because they hold info about the cart, to which the item belongs, the original product (it's id) and the amount. I want to pass a :sellprice value, the final purchase price for the customer, to the lineitems record.

Since I'm adding an item to the cart in the product#show controller, I tried to edit the products.coffee to make the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('div.box form').submit (event) ->
        url = $(this).attr('action')
        sellprice = parseInt( $('#priceValue').text(), 10)
        # console.log(url) <- this works
        # console.log(sellprice) <- this works

        $.ajax
            type: 'PUT'
            url: url
            data: { line_item: { sellprice: sellprice } }
            dataType: 'json'
            success: (json) ->
                console.log('success')
```

But here I receive `PUT http://localhost:9292/line_items?product_id=5 404 (Not Found)` error.
This is what my network tab is showing - http://take.ms/s4zie

I was trying to follow the codeschool level 5 guide and even wrote custom method:

```
def sellprice
        @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
        @line_item.sellprice = params[:line_item][:sellprice]
        @line_item.save

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.json { render json: @line_item.to_json(only: :sellprice) }
        end
    end
```

and made this routes:

```
resources :line_items do
    put :sellprice, on: :member
end
```

in the headers I even see the desired value:

```
Query String Parameters
product_id:5

Form Data
line_item[sellprice]:880
```

but I can't make it work... Please don't be harsh with me, I'm surely missing some basic stuff, but the Ajax things is a whole new world to me (on the other hand I don't know how to pass a JS value into Rails record elsewise).

Comment: Do you have an exception and stacktrace you could could share?  Check your rails console and/or development.log file.  What is the difference between format.js and format.json?  Unless you have a view template for format.js, I would suggest removing it from your respond_to block.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the LineItem being a join table of sorts, but you're passing in the id of the project as the primary key and assuming they will always have the same id.  Shouldn't this use another field when looking up the LineItem?

Comment: @SeanHuber This is what my browser console shows me: `PUT http://localhost:9292/line_items?product_id=5 404 (Not Found)`
My suggestion for the error is following - since my form is for a new line item (because every time a customer adds something to his cart a new line item is created) here I'm trying to update it simultaneously. Thus, the url is for creating a new record, but I'm trying a PUT-verb. If I change the verb to POST, browser console gives me following: `POST http://localhost:9292/line_items?product_id=7 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @BenY I am sorry if my description misled you. I meant not join table of sorts, but "sort of join table" like in "kind of a join table". I am not using a has_many :through, that's why "kind of...".

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the route name in the form definition to something like this:

```
= form_for :line_item, url: line_item_path(@product.id), remote: true do |f|
```

Additionally, if you can set the sellprice as part of the update method, that would be preferable instead of having an additional controller method for this.

Comment: This is what I receive now in my headers:
`Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9292
Request URL:http://localhost:9292/line_items.6
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues. Firstly, as Ben points out, your url is wrong. Its need to be like `/line_items/5`. If you change your `line_items_path(product_id: @product.id)` in your form_for to be `line_items_path(@product)` you should get the correct url generated.

Your second problem is that you are basically doing the ajax request twice - once from the coffee script as a PUT (which should be correct with the change to the url) and once from the form_for with remote set to true. It is the form_for that is doing the "POST" request as you didn't specify a method there.

I would suggest adding the put method (or creating a POST route) to your form_for (`method: :put`) and getting rid of the coffeescript doing the ajax. If you need info from the browser to populate the sellprice, leave that logic in the coffeescript but just update a field value (hidden or otherwise) in your form that will get submitted as part of the form.